# AWS Log Insights replace absent value with 0

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to track **p99** and **p95** for my serverless application.

Standard queries present in the documentation suggest the usage of `@billedDuration`/ `@duration`.

So the query would look like :

```
stats pct(@duration, 99)
```

This does not fit my scenario since for a lambda function, a cold start time would also be associated with some requests.

My query should look something like :

```
stats pct(@duration + @initDuration, 99)
```

However, in my understanding, this only considers the cold start requests and not the requests when cold start time was 0 and hence `@initDuration` field would be absent. So, this query is giving me **p99** of just the cold start requests and not the overall system.

Is there a way I can replace `@initDuration` with 0 if it is blank/ not present? Or is there any other workaround to track actual **p99**/ **p95** for lambdas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `coalesce` function to default `@initDuration` to 0 if not present. Like this:

```
stats pct(@duration + coalesce(@initDuration, 0), 99)
```